# Check recursively if directories in a path exist

Tags: shell, directory

I want to check recursively if directories in a given path exist; if they do not, I want to create them. So if I have the path `/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4`, if want to check first if `dir1/` exists, and if not, create it, then do the same for `dir2/` etc.

Comment: For situations where `mkdir -p` doesn't cut it because you aren't actually looking to *create* the directory tree, consider looking at `basename` and `dirname`.

Comment: I thought of using `basename` and `dirname`, but the problem was that it separates only the last directory from the rest of the tree.

Comment: Put them in an array and iterate over the array in reverse order if you need to create a directory hierarchy (or do something else magical to a path in a top-to-bottom directory approach) without resorting to mkdir -p. Bash shell scripts are actually pretty powerful and can definitely do much more than just invoking simple commands.

Comment: What would be the most efficient way to put them in an array?

Comment: That is unrelated to this question, but [Array variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html) and [The Ultimate Bash Array Tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/) might get you started.

Comment: RE: putting them into an array, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/918931) (obviously replace `;` with `/`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just tell `mkdir` to make the paths with the `-p` switch:

```
$ mkdir -p /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4
```

*excerpt from `mkdir` man page*

```
   -p, --parents
          no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

#### References

- [mkdir man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir)

Comment: Thanks, it is definitely much better than reinventing the wheel as I did with a `while` loop.

Comment: @MBR - yeah the existence of this command switch isn't that intuitive until you've seen it before, then it makes total sense.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, using `cut` and a `while`-loop

```
#!/bin/bash

RUNDIR=$1

n=2
TMPDIR=
while [ $(echo $RUNDIR | cut -d '/' -f$(printf $n)) ]; do
      TMPDIR=$TMPDIR'/'$(echo $RUNDIR | cut -d '/' -f$(printf $n))
      if [ -a $TMPDIR ]; then
         echo $TMPDIR' exists'
      else
         echo $TMPDIR' does not exist; creating directory...'
         mkdir $TMPDIR
      fi
      n=$(printf $(($n + 1)))
done
```

Is there a more compact way to do it?

Comment: Was this an immediate self-answer?

Comment: Lines 9 through 14 (also counting newlines, lines 7-12 of content) can be replaced with something like `test -a "$TMPDIR" || mkdir "$TMPDIR"` if you don't need the output as well. The final `n` increment can be written `n=$(($n + 1))`, no need for `printf` there that I can see. By using `basename` and `dirname` you don't need to parse the path yourself. (And always quote your variables unless you are *positive* that they will *never* contain spaces, and even so, you should quote them anyway just in case.) And even with that, `mkdir -p` as pointed out by @slm is *probably* a better answer. :)

Comment: It was; I was testing things while writing the question, and I figured out this was working though not very compact. Thanks for the improvement suggested!